# As a client; how to present database needs to perspective designers?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-development, document-databases

[I am preparing to solicit proposals for database/project management software design. I know that the quality of the final product will depend on how clearly and completely I can organize and explain the needs of my dept. to perspective consultants.]

What I've done: Started trial accounts with a few free project tracking websites to see if there was anything out there that would work for us 'off the shelf.' Developed a mini SQL database and dug through all of the Microsoft 365 apps (thinking I would be designing this myself). I'm currently developing a comprehensive list of every piece of data that should go into the database. The source, destination, and format of each piece as well as whether or not the data will need to be updated, calculated as needed, remain static... Also, how each user will need to be able to interact with the database, what reports should be generated, etc.

What we need: We need a relational database and a project tracking system. We need to track accounting, spatial data, project design data, etc. Supervisors need to have a 'dashboard' to see how many projects are active, and in what phase. Users need the database to integrate into their workflow to create documents and summary reports. The system should be able to handle workflow prompts so that completion of a task by a user triggers related actions. Data is sensitive, used by a gov't agency, and needs to be secure. Cloud based is a possibility.

Where I'm stuck: I need to figure out what information is necessary when requesting initial proposals, and how to organize it in a way that is meaningful for consultants. I was originally going to draft an ERD to present, but I'm wondering now if that is too much detail, and not enough big picture. I'm trying to dig myself back out of the minutiae to sort out the essential information, and I'm not really sure where to start.

[Is there a format that is helpful to use for organizing the information the designer will need? Specific types of information they will require? Or perhaps resources online that more or less explain the designer's point of view and what they are looking for from a client? How detailed should I be during the initial proposal request?

I have found a few articles explaining concepts of good database design, but they are targeted toward designers, not clients. I'd really appreciate any insights this community might have!]

Comment: If you summarize (and perhaps link to) what you've already found, and how each part is helpful/unhelpful/confusing to you, you may be more likely to get responses here. Perhaps explain your project a bit more.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I didn't see this until after I had edited once, I'll edit again to make it more clear.

Comment: I'm not sure where to begin with posting what I found so far. Before learning that our dept had changed it's mind and wouldn't be getting Microsoft 365 I spent a long time watching tutorials and self-teaching how to use SQLserver + Forms + Flow + etc. to do what I wanted. I have just enough coding experience to understand basic concepts, but I am not a designer and I'm looking at this as a user... I basically plowed right into the middle of things and I'm trying to work my way back to the start.

Comment: Let’s start simple. If I said I’d install MySQL for a hotdog why would you laugh me out of the room?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Not an answer per se *(but I didn’t want to be limited by the
> formatting options in comments)*

First, put yourself in the other person’s shoes. If I were to come to you to request you create something for me, what information would you want to know?

1. Executive summary - ‘elevator speech’

   - What is purpose of the thing
   - Whom does it serve
   - By whom will it be used
2. Requirements

   - Functions - what should go in, what should come out

     - Rough mockups / storyboards (even on napkins) are helpful here

       - Do this for your dashboards
     - Explain in nontechnical terms the purpose of each workflow and how it should function
   - Connections

     - What other systems will data be shared with / retrieved from
     - Which of these are under your control / can those be modified?
   - How will the system be accessed / how many users / backup requirements / etc
   - Access control - home many different levels of permission do you need?
   - Special needs

     - Do you need to store/edit/view things like video, barcodes, PDFs, etc?
3. Detail, if you’re really, really sure *

   - Logical data model

(* the more detail you provide here, the more you lock the developer into your way of thinking - by providing more general requirements they may think of creative ways to architect the thing that you did not - you’re paying them for a reason, right?)

---

**If you don’t want to get caught up in implementation details, imagine instead you’re asking for a magical analog box to be built:**

- This box is made of wood, and it has a shiny brass slot, and a shiny brass tray.
- The box sits on a desk, which also holds several stacks of pre-printed index, a stack of blank index cards, and a pencil.
- The user sits at the desk and either fills out a pre-printed index card with the requested information, or writes a question on a blank card; when complete, they drop the card into the slot.
- A new index card is ejected from the box, into the pretty brass tray. Its message is either:

  1. an answer to the question
  2. a thank-you note for the provided information
  3. a question from the box, asking the user to insert a card with more information

Questions for you:

- What do you want on each type of pre-printed card?
- What questions should the box be able to answer, and what answers are acceptable to each?
- What level of detail would you like in each answer / what kind of information should be included.
- How many desks and boxes do you want?
- Will they be all in the same hall or will they be spread around the city/world?
- Should the box always answer questions, or only at certain times?
- Will the box answer questions of anyone, or should it require the user to sign the index cards they deposit?
- How good of a memory should the box have? Can it answer questions about the past? Do all the magic boxes share a memory, or just have the same abilities?
- Should the box be omniscient, only know what it’s been told, or be able to ask for help answering questions?

---

If nothing else, ask one of your potential vendors what level of detail *they* would like from you.

*(I have to go perform first aid on a pet rabbit now - hopefully this is a useful start)*

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to spell that out for me, and I hope your rabbit is doing well! It is certainly a useful start, and I will use the outline you've provided. One other thing I thought of; do I need to provide any sort of estimate of scale (e.g., size/quantity of information, or future projections of the scope of the program and growth of projects)?

Comment: A sense of scale would be helpful, preferably as a range. A database designed to catalog the work of a two-person department will have vastly different deployment considerations than one designed to be used across a global business or by the public. Feel free to think outside the box - perhaps write up a question / answer document - brainstorm with your team what questions might be asked by the person you will interview, then answer them in writing. You don’t necessarily have to show this to anyone, but it may help in your thinking process.